# Openshift: Trying to create java.websocket using JBoss Application Server

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, jboss7.x, openshift

I am new to open shift, so bear with me. I have gotten open shift on my eclipse, and I have set up a JBoss Application Server 7. I want to make a server endpoint java class as described [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.3/html/Development_Guide/Create_a_Websocket_Application.html). How do I do this? I noticed that, first of all, there is no java.websocket jar files in the open shift project that I created in eclipse. So I decided to import it and added to the build path. (This jar file I copied from glassfish's javax.websocket-api.jar). But whenever I would commit it and push my java class, it would give me a bunch of errors and mu open shift domain won't work.

So what am I doing wrong? Is it that the jar file that I imported is wrong (i.e. it isn't compatible with JBoss)?
Another thing that eclipse is telling me is that there is this error: "Faceted Project Problem (Java Version Mismatch) (1 item)"

Here is my server endpoint class:

```
package serverendpointdemo;

import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnError;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint("/serverendpointdemo")
public class ServerEndPointDemo {
    @OnOpen
    public void handleOpen () {
        System.out.println("JAVA: Client is now connected...");
    }

    @OnMessage
    public String handleMessage (String message) {
        System.out.println("JAVA: Received from client: "+ message);
        String replyMessage = "echo "+ message;
        System.out.println("JAVA: Send to client: "+ replyMessage);
        return replyMessage;
    }

    @OnClose
    public void handleClose() {
        System.out.println("JAVA: Client is now disconnected...");
    }

    @OnError
    public void handleError (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help!